# Erro ao tentar varrer um array

Tags: java, array, loop

Estou tentando varrer o array dentro do laço, conforme o código abaixo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RapidoPora {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] nota = new int[10];



        for(int c = 0; c < 11; c++) {


            System.out.println(nota[c]);

        }




}


}
```

Mas ocorre essa exceção:

> ```
>  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
>         at RapidoPora.main(RapidoPora.java:15)
>     0
>     0
>     0
>     0
>     0
>     0
>     0
>     0
>     0
>     0
> ```

O que pode ser?

Answer (score 3):

Se o tamanho do vetor é 10 posicoes, voce somente tem 10 posicoes para percorrer, e nao 11 como está no seu laço. Altere para:

```
int[] nota = new int[10];


 for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {


     System.out.println(nota[c]);

 }
```

Veja funcionando no ideone: https://ideone.com/SFfEAa

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaahh valeu passarinho

Comment: @ProgramadorJaveiro se a resposta lhe ajudou, você pode aceita-la clicando no `v`, assim você encerra a pergunta e marca que encontrou a solução :)

Answer (score -2):

O erro se refere ao estouro do indice do vetor.
O correto seria:

```
for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {

            System.out.println(nota[c]);

        }
```

Comment: Eu já havia respondido isso, olhe a outra resposta postada há 5 horas atras.